# How does laravel parse routes into component parts?

Tags: php, laravel

It became curious, how does laravel parse routes and understand which route to match with the correct url? For example url be processed by the appropriate route?

```
www.ru/post/100/comments/500

Route::get('/posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', [NameConroller::class, 'show']);
```

At first glance,

1. it seems that we should split the incoming route (for example explode()) by /.
2. Then find all routes where the first part starts with /post
3. From the routes found in the previous paragraph, we should understand (how?) that /{post} matches any number. Etc.

Perhaps someone dug into the source code or just knows how it works? It would be interesting to know)

Comment: Using an IDE like PHPStorm allows you to easily find the definitions of functions, if you know where to start. Starting with [Routing/Route::compileRoute](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php), you find it's a [Symfony routing function](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.php), and finally goes down to the `compile` function of [the symfony RouteCompiler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/RouteCompiler.php). That should get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all happens here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L153

Laravel loops through all your routes until it find a match which is checked here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L328

If you look at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Matching/UriValidator.php you would see that `/posts/{post}/comments/{comment}` gets compiled to `{^/posts/(?P<post>[^/]++)/comments/(?P<comment>[^/]++)$}sDu` and it checked with regex

For an explanation on the regex look here https://regex101.com/r/VgsiHI/1

The first url to match is the route that gets the request

Comment: A regular expression like {^/posts/(?P<post>[^/]++)/comments/(?P<comment>[^/]++)$}sDu
Passes both a route like /posts/123/comments/321 and a route like /posts/all/comments/fail

Comment: Yes, you can control the valid matches using various where methods on the route https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints in our example if you were to add `->whereNumber('post')` the compiled regex would be a bit different `{^/posts/(?P<post>[0-9]+)/comments/(?P<comment>[^/]++)$}sDu` notice now instead of accepting any characters it only accepts 0-9 as a match for `post`

Comment: It's fine. So, if we collect a regular subexpression like (?P<post>[\d+$]++), we can track only numeric parameters?

Comment: [\d] and [0-9] are essentially the same. if you want to see what it generates you can paste these two lines in tinker `$routes = (fn () => $this->routes)->call(app('router'));`
`dd((fn () => $this->compileRoute())->call($routes->getRoutes()[0]));`